# How can you transfer items in battle?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, action-economy

When I say item, I mean armour, weapon, materials etc. Can you transfer items across distance without using movement or throwing them preferably without using the bonus action of the sender?

Comment: Related, could possibly answer this question : https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/131080/77044

Comment: Can you explain how far you are trying to transfer items? 10 feet? 30 feet? 100 feet?  That makes a difference in the problem you are trying to solve.  Also, [are you familiar with Interacting with an object?](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=73) - and how it applies to your question?

Comment: “Preferably without throwing them.” How else are you picturing moving the objects? Magic? Otherwise, you could only transfer them as far as you could reach…